# What is the name of this application?

Tags: macos, applications

To be honest, the icon got me curious

What is the name of this application?

[image]

Comment: How did you get the application without knowing?

Comment: YouTube video :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.microsoft.com/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps

Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Found by using reverse image search.